# How to load model and weights using tensorflow.js in browser saved on Node.js?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow.js

Source: [Save / load model docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/model-save-load.html)

I have trained multiple models on nodeJS side and saved them to using "file://"

So I have 1 JSON file, and 1 binary file with weights

But to load this model on browser side I can use only localStorage, indexedDB and HTTP requests.

What is the correct way to load them?

I cant just load from localStorage before I put a model there.
Maybe somehow I can convert my two files in something JSON-like and put it to localStorage?

IndexedDB is being cleaned after browser restart. Not sure if I can use it.

Http seems fine, but how do I load weights using?

```
await tf.loadModel('http://model-server.domain/download/model.json')
```

Its just a single file request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weight files are loaded automatically by using the same path as the model file.
With your example the model file has url as following:
http://model-server.domain/download/model.json

The loader will load the weight files from following url:
http://model-server.domain/download/group1-shard1of1

As long as you store the weight files the same directory as the model.json file on the server, it should work.

Comment: Indeed. Tried to serve directory using nodeJS/express. 
const loadedModel = await tf.loadModel(`http://localhost:8085/${modelName}/model.json`);
And it worked. 
But is there a way to do it on offline machine without running servers (like node)? 
I can use chrome with any security flags (ex. --allow-file-access-from-files).